# Adobe Flex flash screens have 4 second lag before launch

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, actionscript, flash-builder

I have a system that has an application that loads Flex modules. what I'm seeing is that I make the request to load the application, and there is a 4 second lag before the Initialize is called in the application.  Then everything runs as normal, until I make a web request, then there is another 4 second lag before the request goes out.

I have found that Flash 11.5 on IE 9 is slow, and even the latest 11.6 is slow on IE 8.  But if I update IE9 to 11.6, or run it from firefox everything works without the delay.

I'm using FlashBuilder 4.6, but using the 4.5.1A SDK.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: Any differences observed when using the debug Flash Player versus the release (non-debug) version? Is HTTPS being used? You might do a tail -f on your web server access logs or use a "web inspector" (like firebug, but whatever is appropriate for IE) to see what's going on w/the http requests.

Comment: Can you share the nature of data and its size, you are requesting? I was experiencing some delay while using the SOAP WS to pull a considerable amount of data.

Comment: We are using HTTPRequest and getting an XML response.  I've used fiddler and other timing tools, based on the timing logs the lag isn't in waiting for the response, it's almost like Flash Player has delays because there is 4 seconds between when the flash was launchedand onInitialize is called.  Same with from the time the HTTPRequest is made in the code until I see the request go out on Fiddler, 4 seconds.